# Adding event handlers Dynamically to controls within a panel

Tags: c#, events, dynamic, panel, handler

I've a class which is in a nutshell:

```
class MyPanel
{
    Panel p_panel;                     //declaring all the elements I need
    CheckBox cb_choice;
    RadioButton rb_nagy, rb_kicsi;
    TextBox tb_db;

    public Panel getPanel() {        
        create();                     //creating all the elements I need, then putting them all in the created Panel.
        customize();                  //setting the panel's size, and the other control's locations within the panel.
        return p_panel;               //so if I call this method from an other class, this method will return a panel with all the controls inside.
```

In the other class, I've a list of Panels all of which have been created with the above method.
The layout is done, and it works neatly, I can add as many as I want to the screen. but now I want to add some function to these controls. For example, I want all the radiobuttons disabled unless the checkbox is enabled.
So how can I add a check changed event to all the checkboxes that are in the list of panels?

Comment: In the event handler for the checkbox (value changed or whatever it is), could you do this pseudocode `if enabled, disable radio buttons`? Is that what you mean?

Comment: I need code that does that on the fly, dynamically, within each individual member of the panels list.

Comment: Your problem description is a little vague for me to really answer that -- I'm not really sure how you want each checkbox to specifically interact with the radio buttons... but events wired up to each checkbox should do the trick. I won't just give you the code, you have to try something first.

Comment: Instead of dynamically creating the interface, add a **UserControl** to your project and place all these controls on it at design-time.  Then you can add code to the UserControl...why are doing it the "hard way"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just want to know how to dynamically add `EventHandler`s to your controls!?

It can be done like this:

```
cb_choice.CheckedChanged += cb_choice_CheckedChanged;
```

or if you want to be more explicit (both ways work the same).

```
cb_choice.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cb_choice_CheckedChanged);
```

And define a handler method:

```
private void cb_choice_CheckedChanged(object o, EventArgs args)
{
    //add code to enable/disable radiobuttons
}
```